# C# - error CS0123 A method or delegate parameters do not match delegate parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types, delegates

I am stuck at an error that I can understand but cannot fix, it's a CS0123 error where parameters between a method and a delegate do not match. But I looked at my code and it seems to be the right type so I'm confused and ask for your help since I'm learning more advanced C# with this project. This project is about to generate an hex grid and then process an A* pathfinding on it between two hex tiles. I used [this serie of written tutorials](https://tbswithunity3d.wordpress.com/) even if it's an old one and had to refresh a bit the code to make it work on Unity 5 and more recent version of C# .NET (I guess).

Here are the errors :

**Assets/Scripts/GridManager.cs(151,39): error CS0123: A method or delegate 'GridManager.calcDistance(Tile)' parameters do not match delegate 'System.Func()' parameters**

**Assets/Scripts/GridManager.cs(153,17): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'GridManager.DrawPath(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments**

**Assets/Scripts/GridManager.cs(153,17): error CS1503: Argument '#1' cannot convert 'object' expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'**

I'm pretty sure that the two lasts are there only because of the first because it does not recognize the right var type that should be a Tile.

I hope you'll be able to help me and explain me what I did wrong. I think I do not entirely what's going on there.

Thank you in advance !

Here is some of my modified code but it's basically the same as the tutorial :

GridManager.cs :

```
    double calcDistance(Tile tile)
    {
            Tile destTile = destTileTB.tile;
            float deltaX = Mathf.Abs(destTile.X - tile.X);
            float deltaY = Mathf.Abs(destTile.Y - tile.Y);
            int z1 = -(tile.X + tile.Y);
            int z2 = -(destTile.X + destTile.Y);
            float deltaZ = Mathf.Abs(z2 - z1);

            return Mathf.Max(deltaX, deltaY, deltaZ);
    }

    private void DrawPath(IEnumerable<Tile> path)
    {
            if (this.path == null)
                    this.path = new List<GameObject>();
            this.path.ForEach(Destroy);
            this.path.Clear();

            GameObject lines = GameObject.Find("Lines");
            if (lines == null)
                    lines = new GameObject("Lines");
            foreach (Tile tile in path)
            {
                    var line = (GameObject)Instantiate(Line);
                    Vector2 gridPos = new Vector2(tile.X + tile.Y / 2, tile.Y);
                    line.transform.position = calcWorldCoord(gridPos);
                    this.path.Add(line);
                    line.transform.parent = lines.transform;
            }
    }

    public void generateAndShowPath()
    {
            if (originTileTB == null || destTileTB == null)
            {
                    DrawPath(new List<Tile>());
                    return;
            }
            Func<Tile, Tile, double> distance = (node1, node2) => 1;

            var path = PathFinder.FindPath(originTileTB.tile, destTileTB.tile,
                                           distance, calcDistance); //error is here
            DrawPath(path);
    }
```

PathFinder.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public static class PathFinder
    {
    public static Path<Node> FindPath<Node>(
            Node start,
            Node destination,
            Func<Node, Node, double> distance,
            Func<Node> estimate)
            where Node : IHasNeighbours<Tile>
    {
            var closed = new HashSet<Node>();
            var queue = new PriorityQueue<double, Path<Node>>();
            queue.Enqueue(0, new Path<Node>(start));

            while (!queue.IsEmpty)
            {
                    var path = queue.Dequeue();

                    if (closed.Contains(path.LastStep))
                            continue;
                    if (path.LastStep.Equals(destination))
                            return path;

                    closed.Add(path.LastStep);

                    foreach (Node n in path.LastStep.Neighbours)
                    {
                            double d = distance(path.LastStep, n);
                            var newPath = path.AddStep(n, d);
                            queue.Enqueue(newPath.TotalCost + estimate(n), newPath);
                    }
            }

            return null;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the FindPath method, you define estimate to be a Func that takes no arguments and return a node, yet when calling the method you pass in calcDistance that takes a tile and returns a double.  It looks like estimate should be a Func that takes a Node and returns a double.

```
public static Path<Node> FindPath<Node>(
        Node start,
        Node destination,
        Func<Node, Node, double> distance,
        Func<Node, double> estimate)
```

Comment: It worked but reveals a lot of errors everywhere else. I managed to fix it and now everything's just fine. So thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

> var path = PathFinder.FindPath(originTileTB.tile, destTileTB.tile,
>                                              distance, calcDistance); //error is here

well there seems to be lot of mistakes precisely the error is when you try to pass `calcDistance` and if you see the expected input it is `Func<node> estimate` which means it is looking for a delegate that returns type `Node`. Clearly your `calcDistance` is a function not a delegate.

hence the error.

Comment: I need more work delegates but thanks to this, I know understand more on that subject. Thank you for your answer !